# jQueryMobile-Timebox issue(not showing AM/PM block)

Tags: jquery-mobile, plugins, time

I am using Datebox(http://dev.jtsage.com/DateBox/) plugin to let user choose time in a specific format, but that plugin only generating 2 blocks and didn't showing the third block for AM/PM(as shown in demos), I am mentioning my html/scripts below please help me to find out whats going wrong.

```
<input type="text" name="startDate" id="filter-date-from" value="" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode":"timebox","overrideTimeFormat":"%l:%M %p","overrideTimeOutput":"%l:%M %p","popupPosition":"window"}'>
```

```js
    <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="plugins/DateBox/css/jtsage-datebox.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
     <script src="plugins/DateBox/js/jtsage-datebox.min.js"></script>
```

-I have downloaded Datebox plugin and saved inside "plugins" folder and hence given the desired path at the top.
-saved jquer.js, jquerymobile.js in js forlder and hence given the path at top, same is done for css